# Android Google Maps Api V2 crashes

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api, samsung-mobile

i'm trying to make an `Android App` using `Google Maps Api`, for that I followed the same step (exact) made by the famous (Ravi Tamada ) is his tutorial:

Link to the tutorial: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/

but when I try to compile the project an run it on my Android device `(Samsung Galaxy S3, Android Version: 4.1.2)` it crashes and gives me the following error msg in the LogCast!

Link to My LogCast: http://openensak.com/img/LogCast.png

i don't know what's wrong !!!

Comment: can you post your xml file.. there is a error in your xml file..

Comment: hey @shylendra which Xml u mean the manifest or layout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
YourActivity extends FragmentActivity
```

instead of

```
import android.app.Fragment;
YourActivity extends Activity
```

and    Please add the API KEY in your manifest file

```
<application>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="youApiKey" 

        />
    <meta-data 
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" 
        />
</application>
```

is in the  element of AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

I think you can not include google-play-services.jar to your project. Because of that, fragment in your layout can not be inflated. Be sure about adding google-play-services.jar to your project. Or add your class

`import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`
and instead of using

`public class MainActivity extends Activity`

use  `public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity`